# Does Guice guarantee when dependencies are created?

Tags: guice

I notice that Guice may inject a proxy for a provider and defer the construction of the actual provider class until when the provider is used.

```
public static class Foo {
  private final Provider<Bar> barProvider;

  @Inject
  public Foo(Provider<Bar> barProvider) {
    this.barProvider = barProvider;
  }

  public Bar getBar() {
    return barProvider.get();
  }
}

public static class Bar {
  @Inject
  public Bar() {}
}

public static class BarProvider implements Provider<Bar> {
  public BarProvider() {
    System.out.println("BarProvider constructed");
  }
  @Override
  public Bar get() {
    return null;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Bar.class).toProvider(BarProvider.class);
    }
  });
  Foo foo = injector.getInstance(Foo.class);
  System.out.println("Foo created by Guice");
  foo.getBar();
}
```

Output is

```
Foo created by Guice
BarProvider constructed
```

Does this happen with Provider injections only, or it could happen with non-provider injections too? I understand that when circular dependencies appear, Guice does need to use proxy. But I am concerned that if the latter is true, then Guice cannot guarantee everything is REALLY constructed at the end of `Injector.getInstance(some_class)`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on applied **scope** and **stage**. There is a link to guice doc which describe it http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes

Well, if you bind **Bar.class** as EagerSingleton, then bind classes are instantized immediately, so application startup is a bit prolonged.

```
bind(Bar.class).toProvider(BarProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
```

The output will be different

```
BarProvider constructed
Foo created by Guice
```

There are three stages, you can set them during **Guice.createInjector**

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, new AbstractModule() {
```

Comment: `Bar` may not be singleton.